Why is the line spacing between the bullet points so low?
Why is the line spacing between the bullet points so low? I want to have the line spacing by 1.25

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb} %for \blacksquare
\usepackage{multienum}

\newcommand{\rsqr}{\raisebox{0.4ex}{\tiny $\blacksquare$}}

\newlength\myindent
\newlength\mylen

\renewcommand{\itemxx}[2]{%
  \setlength\mylen{\remainxx}
  \addtolength\mylen{-\myindent}
  \hskip\myindent
  \parbox[t]{\labelwidth}{\hfill\labelenumi}%
  \hskip\labelsep
  \parbox[t]{0.5\mylen}{\raggedright #1}%
  \hfill\parbox[t]{\labelwidth}{\hfill\labelenumi}%
  \hskip\labelsep
  \parbox[t]{0.5\mylen}{\raggedright #2}\smallskip}


\newenvironment{listable}[1][0cm]
  {\begin{multienumerate}
  \setlength\myindent{#1}
    \renewcommand\labelenumi{\rsqr}
    \setlength\itemsep{-.5\baselineskip}
  }
  {\end{multienumerate}}

\begin{document}

\begin{listable}
    \mitemxx{Lots and lots of text, oh my!Lots and lots of text, oh my!Lots and lots of text, oh my!Lots and lots of text, oh my!Lots and lots of text, oh my!Lots and lots of text, oh my!}{More and more text}
    \mitemxx{word}{All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy}
\end{listable}

\begin{listable}[4em]
    \mitemxx{Lots and lots of text, oh my!}{More and more text}
    \mitemxx{word}{All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy}
\end{listable}

\end{document}






\setlength\itemsep{-.5\baselineskip} might have something to do with it.

Are you trying to define macros for nested lists?
